# Expose recorded list of votes before reputation allowed voting

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, post-feedback

For the last couple of years on Super User I used to +1 a question or answer and it always said I did not have a reputation of 15 so it was not counted, but it said that my vote was recorded none-the-less. The same happens on all Stack Exchange sites, including here on Meta.

I finally sat down for an hour yesterday and answered some questions on Super User to get my reputation up.

Now I would like to access a list of all my recorded votes which were not official so I can back-date my appreciation.

Please, can this functionality be added so one can see this list in one's profile?